# Groovy: tokenize string up to 3rd occurence of delimiter only

Tags: string, groovy, split, tokenize

I want to tokenize string up to 3rd occurence of some delimiter and then return the rest of the string as last element of the tokenize array.
Example:
I have a String which looks like this:

```
String someString= 1.22.33.4
```

Now im tokenizing it by delimiter '.' like this:

```
def (a, b, c, d) = someString.tokenize('.')
```

And it works, but only if number of dots are exactly 3.
Now if someone puts more number of dots like:

```
String someString = 1.22.33.4.55
```

Then it wouldn't work, because the number of variables won't match. So i want to make sure it only tokenizes up to 3rd dot, and then gives back whatever is left. So what i want to achieve in this case would be:

```
a = 1, b=22, c=33, d=4.55
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the version of `split` with the second argument to restrict
the returned items.  E.g.

```
def (a,b,c,d) = '1.22.33.4.55'.split("\\.", 4)
assert ["1","22","33","4.55"] == [a,b,c,d]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a one liner but it works:

```
String someString= '1.22.33.4.55'
def stringArray = someString.tokenize('.')
def (a,b,c) = stringArray
def d = stringArray.drop(3).join('.')

println "a=$a, b=$b, c=$c, d=$d"
```

result:

```
a=1, b=22, c=33, d=4.55
```